# What does this purple 'T' icon mean in Visual Studio/TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, icons

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, linked up to TFS 2012 for source control.

I've just branched some code, but after creating the branch files it told me I don't have 'Manage Branch' permission.

Not an issue, I can sort that, but my Google skills are failing me when it comes to working out exactly what this little purple 'T' icon means in the source explorer window.

[image]

I presume it's a pending change?

LATER THAT DAY : After sorting the permissions out, I checked the new branch in ok and the icon disappeared, but I'd still like to know what it meant, and how to identify any other icons that might appear.

Comment: Is this specific to VS2012?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's just the new VS2012 icon for a pending Branch action. If you look closely, it's not a 'T' but actually an upwards facing split arrow.  A larger version of the icon can be seen if you look at the File -> Source Control -> Branching and Merging -> Branch menu item.

Normally you won't see this since branch actions are usually performed server side. In your case since you didn't have permissions it was tracked as a pending branch request, and cleared once your permission problem was resolved.

Comment: Just saw this for the first time in VS2017, it also appears whenever a pending branch has not been committed via check-in.

Answer (score 15):

**When you check in your new branch the purple icon will disappear.**

The purple T symbol will be shown next to all files in a newly created branch that has pending changes (the branch is created but not checked in). I assume this is the 'pending change' indicator at source control or branching level.